# Windows based Apache/PHP/Perl/database stacks

Tags: windows, perl, xampp, postgresql

Does anyone know if XAMPP's Perl also provides Tk support?  Does anyone know of a similar stack which provides PostresSQL in addition to/instead of MySQL?  I'd like this to run on Win 7 and XP.

Edit:  I do know I could install the other components I want "by hand", for example getting Tk from CPAN, I'd just prefer to get everything at one time if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having not received any answers, I'll supply one based on my experiences.  At this stage, this is somewhat preliminary, as I've not had a lot of free time to resolve all the issues I've encountered.

I didn't find any distributions which had Apache, PHP, Perl, and PostgreSQL (which I want because that's what we use at work), so I downloaded and installed XAMPP.

It turns out that XAMPP does not distribute Tk (understandable, since I wouldn't expect that to be useful for web stuff).  I did grab Tk from CPAN; however, I only found source.  The build files which come with Tk expect a Microsoft C compiler & make system.  I have Visual Studio C++ (Express), which includes nmake and the cl compiler.  Unfortunately, Visual Studio doesn't pre-configure itself for command line use.  At this point, I'm still working through issues to get that to run so I can build and use Tk.

Eventually I hope to download & install PostgreSQL.

More if/when I get things working.